# Print preview not as rendered in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to print a gridview as rendered, but all the linebreaks are ignored.

EG

This

1. Something
2. Something
3. Something

is printet as

1. Something2. Something3. Something

I have a script like this

```
 <script>
    function printpage() {

        var getpanelToPrint = document.getElementById("<%= PnlToPrint.ClientID%>");
         var MainWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800');
         MainWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Page</title>');
         MainWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
         MainWindow.document.write(getpanel.innerHTML);
         MainWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
         MainWindow.document.close();
         setTimeout(function () {
             MainWindow.print();
         }, 500);
         return false;

     }
</script>
```

I have tried HtmlEncode = True and False ind the BoundField DataField

Any ideas to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function printPage() {
                var getpanelToPrint = document.getElementById("<%= PnlToPrint.ClientID%>");
                var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = getpanelToPrint;
                document.body.style.margin = "10%";
                document.body.style.pageBreakAfter = "always";               
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but all i get is this "[object HTMLDivElement]".